# イベント「Winter Bash」は廃止されました

Tags: サポート, winter-bash

毎年12月中旬から開始されていた恒例のイベント「Winter Bash」は廃止されました。[Stack Exchange社により発表](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/392846/348970)されています（来年以降の話では無く、今年 — 2023年から開催されません）。

理由としては、イベントに参加するユーザーは少なく、貢献を促進する効果も無く、コンセプトは陳腐化し、運営コストが大きいことが挙げられています。