# 結果発表：9 周年イベント第一弾「Winter Badge」 

Tags: 討議, バッジ, キャンペーン

ユーザーのみなさまに支えられ、2023年12月16日（土）にスタック・オーバーフローは 9 周年を迎えます。これを記念して、9 周年記念イベント第一弾「Winter Badge」を開催します！

<sup>*恒例の Stack Overflow イベント「[Winter Bash](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/392846/314875) 」は[廃止](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3947/14055)されましたが、その代わりに名前が少しアレンジされた「Winter Badge 」を @[payaneco さん](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/9820/payaneco)が[ご提案](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/64816349#64816349)くださいました。*</sup>

UTC 期間中に下記のバッジを獲得した方に、 公式 Stack Overflow 靴下をプレゼントします。
[image]

- [**ひらめき**](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/19/enlightened)
  最初に回答してスコア 10 以上で承認された
- [**蘇生術**](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/64/revival)
  質問投稿後 30 日以上たってから最初の回答を投稿し、スコア 2 以上を獲得した
- [**復活の呪文**](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/17/necromancer)
  質問投稿後 60 日以上たってから回答し、スコアが 5 以上
- [**篤志家**](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/48/altruist)
  別のユーザーの質問に初めて手動で懸賞を授与した
- [**呼び込み**](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/59/announcer)
  投稿へのリンクを共有後、25 の異なるIPアドレスからアクセスされた

**バッジ獲得期間**
2023年12月16日（土）〜　2023年12月30日（土）

注: バッジの獲得の判定は即時的には計算されていません。不定期に実行されるクエリにより行なわれます。よって、期間中に条件を満たしても、今回のキャンペーンには間に合わない可能性があります。逆に、条件を満たしたのが開始前であっても、期間中に授与されて対象になる可能性もあります。このズレは[99%の場合24時間以下だそうです](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/1721/)。

**結果発表**
2024年1月4日（木）

さぁ、バッジを獲得して、一緒に素敵な冬を楽しみましょう⛄️！

Comment: 細かい部分ですが、蘇生術と呼び込みもメタバッジではなくネットワークバッジですか？(そもそもメタバッジは含まない認識でよろしいですか？)

Comment: @payaneco メインサイトを盛り上げるのが目的なので、それらのタグもメタではなくメインサイトを指すよう修正しました。(メタでの信用度等はそれほど重要じゃないので…) / aki 問題あればロールバックをお願いします。

Comment: @cubick ご対応ありがとうございました。

Comment: みなさんのサポートに支えられ、素敵なイベントを共に創り上げていけることに心から感謝しています！ロールバックなどとんでもございません。

Comment: クエリを作ってみました。https://data.stackexchange.com/ja/query/edit/1810750 Parametersの`fromDate`に`2023/12/16`を、`toDate`に`2023/12/31`を入力するとWinnerが取得できるはずです。

Comment: @payaneco Data Exporter は、週に一回の更新であることに注意が必要です。
また、更新直後であれば最新に近いかというと、そうとも限りません。
例えば、今現在は更新されたばかりですが、私が先ほど確認したところ1週間古いデータでした。
これは普通ではないはずなので対応中だと思いますが、いずれにしろ、いつのデータを見ているのかは常に確認する必要が有ります。

Comment: @mjy ご指摘ありがとうございます。過去データや自分のデータのみで確認していました。取扱注意ということでよろしくお願いします。

Comment: クエリ作成ありがとうございました！結果発表をお正月明けに延ばしました。

Answer (score 6):

**結果発表**：

**yohjp さん**
[image: yohjp] [蘇生術](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/64/revival) & [呼び込み](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/59/announcer)

**payaneco さん**
[image: payaneco] [蘇生術](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/64/revival)

**mjy さん**
[image: mjy] [ひらめき](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/19/enlightened)

おめでとうございます！！！後日、Winner のみなさまへ賞品の発送に関するメールをお送りいたします。

イベントのご提案、投稿の改善、チャットでアドバイスをくださったみなさま、そしてご参加いただいた全ての方々へ心より感謝申し上げます️。